# Why grammarly.com did remove comma here "They have just discovered a new fuel - it's half the price of petrol, and much cleaner."

Tags: american-english, commas

In "How English Works" page 172, 16 "They have just discovered a new fuel - it's half the price of petrol, and much cleaner."
Why grammarly.com remove comma after petrol: 
"They have just discovered a new fuel - it's half the price of petrol and much cleaner."
I ask this question by thinking is there a difference between AmE and BrE in the position of the comma. The book is by Oxford University Press UK and Grammarly.com is American English.

Comment: I suggest that you change your question to ask if one way or the other is correct or not. I think only the developers of Grammarly can explain why the program does this or that. As the question stands now, I'm voting to close it as off-topic. You are welcome to edit the question if it's really about English, not about how a computer program works.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about English.

Comment: @JimReynolds I ask this question by thinking is there a difference between AmE and BrE in the position of the comma. The book is by Oxford University Press UK and Grammarly.com is American English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least two reasons Grammarly might have removed the comma:

1. Because the use of "and" produces a list context (a, b, c and d) and it's becoming less common to separate the last element of a list with a comma.
2. It's also possible they considered "a and b" to be a compound adjective of "fuel."

However, it's not wrong to have the comma, if you want it.<sup>1</sup>  For example, it's legitimate to consider the phrase "and much cleaner" to be clause (often separated with a comma), or you may simply want to emphasize that last bit of information.

The use of commas is a complex issue because there are so many exceptions to the rules.  Worse, in many situations how commas are used is often a style decision, not a grammar decision.

Regrettably, if you really want to know why Grammarly removed the comma, you'll need to ask Grammarly.  I, for one, would be curious to know their response.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> *That sentence contains a bit of humor, because the comma is optional.*</sub>